# Is this functional $f \mapsto \int |f|^2 dx $ Frechet differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, frechet-derivative

Suppose $(X, \mathcal M, \mu)$ is a fixed measure space. For $f \in L^2(X)$, i.e., $f : X \to \mathbb C$ is measurable and $\int |f(x)|^2 d\mu(x) < \infty$, we define a functional $\phi : L^2(X) \to \mathbb R$ by
\begin{align*}
f \mapsto \int |f|^2 d \mu = \int f^* fd\mu.
\end{align*}
I am wondering whether or not $\phi$ is Frechet differentiable with respect to the norm topology on $L^2(X)$.

If we consider some small $g \in L^2(X)$, then
\begin{align*}
\phi(f+g) &= \int (f+g)^*(f+g) d \mu = \int |f|^2 d \mu + \int (f^*g+g^* f)d\mu + \int |g|^2 d \mu \\
&= \phi(f) + \int Re(f^* g) d \mu + \int|g|^2 d\mu.
\end{align*}
It seems that the middle term defines a bounded linear functional by $g \mapsto \int Re(f^* g) d \mu$ but I am not sure this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a set of measure one.

Pick $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and define the function $z 1_A$. Note that
$\phi(z 1_A) = |z|^2$ and define
$f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $f(z) = \phi(z 1_A)$.
Note that $f$ is not differentiable. Hence $\phi$ is not differentiable.

Comment: I am a little bit confused why $\phi(z 1_A) = |z|^2$. Should it be zero since $\phi(z1_A) = \int_A z^* z d \mu$?

Comment: Z is a constant. A has measure one. How can it be zero?

Comment: Sorry. I misread. Not sure why I read $A$ is measure 0.

Comment: I'm confused by both of you :) it seems to me the original question has the answer right, that $|z|^2$ is perfectly differentiable, and that the bit that is correct about this answer is the formula for $\phi(z1_A)$

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks. This is not the original question: this functional $\phi$ should be subdifferentiable, right? Since $\phi = \|\cdot\|^2$ is convex over $L^2$.

Comment: Ah, I guess the question is whether we're talking about real or complex Frechet diferentiability. Since we have a complex space I guess it's fair that you assume the latter

Comment: But since Cindy now talks about subdifferentiability it seems she assumes the former

Comment: OK. Now I see the point. I did not think about the difference between real or complex Frechet differentiability and was assuming for complex. Is there a difference?